# How to display newly added image file with gatsby-image?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

In my Gatsby app user is able to upload an image which is being saved locally and ideally displayed but `gatsby-image` doesn't see new image this is how my `Image.js` file looks like.

I'm thinking that the graphql data needs to be somehow refreshed because the new image doesn't even show if I do `console.log(data.images)` but how can I do that?

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Image = props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        images: allFile {
          edges {
            node {
              relativePath
              name
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1200) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {
      console.log(data.images)
      const image = data.images.edges.find(n => {
        return n.node.relativePath.includes(props.filename)
      })
      if (!image) {
        return null
      }
      return (
        <Img
          alt={props.alt}
          fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid}
          style={props.customStyle}
        />
      )
    }}
  />
)

export default Image
```

Also gatsby recognizes that new file is added and prints this in terminal after file is added

```
info added file at D:\WebsitesProjects\Portfolio\Ecommerce\images\daf27e67-01e5-4ba1-a25b-2348f4340eae.jpg
info changed file at D:\WebsitesProjects\Portfolio\Ecommerce\images\daf27e67-01e5-4ba1-a25b-2348f4340eae.jpg
success building schema - 0.421s
info Total nodes: 82, SitePage nodes: 14 (use --verbose for breakdown)
success createPages - 0.001s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
success update schema - 0.026s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
success extract queries from components - 0.758s
success write out requires - 0.006s
success run static queries - 0.176s - 2/2 11.33/s
success Generating image thumbnails - 0.162s - 3/3 18.54/s
```

I tried using `gatsby-plugin-node-reload` but it doesn't seem to work. Here are my `gatsby-config.js` plugins

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `../images`),
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-node-reload",
  ],
```

also everything works perfectly if I restart app after saving new image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you need to refresh/rebuild the application to update the system with your image. Gatsby, compiles, bundles and processes all the assets in the build/develop time so if you add a fresh image, you will need to rebuild your application to allow Gatsby to create a schema and a node for that image.

Given your scenario, you have a few options:

- Use a native `img` tag and recreate the benefits of `gatsby-image` using others third-party dependencies ([lazyloading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload), etc).
- Create a [webhook](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052324394-Using-webhooks-in-Gatsby-Cloud) to trigger a rebuild when an image is uploaded. A webhook is a way for an application to notify another application when a new event has occurred in real-time. I wouldn't recommend this approach since it will cause a breakdown in your application while it's being deployed.
- Use some other SSR framework rather than Gatsby.